# Killing GNU screen session using php

Tags: php, linux, session, kill, gnu-screen

I'm hosting a gameserver for my mate on my VPS, and I tried to make a webpage for him to stop the server if he wants.

What I'm using is:

`system('/bin/sh stopserver.sh');`

this is what is inside stopserver.sh:

`/usr/bin/screen -S server -X kill`

but all this gives me is this message: Must be connected to a terminal.

Any advice?

Comment: Why are you using screen to kill the server?

Comment: oops, i fixed it but it still says must be connected to terminal, and to first commenter: it's running on a screen session

Comment: Is the webserver running under the same user as the screen-session? Otherwise it wont work (or you have to use "sudo").

Comment: why not just send SIGTERM to the server or screen process?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a bug in the version of screen you're using, since the one I have, `4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06`, doesn't exhibit it.  I'd recommend upgrading, if possible.

If you can't upgrade screen, you need to figure out some way to provide it with a terminal.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that.  It seems that in some versions of PHP [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) may have been able to do that, at least if PHP was compiled with the right options, but [apparently that feature has been removed](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39224).

One possible long shot could be to use [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), if it's installed on your system.

Edit: Or just do as tMC suggests and use [`posix_kill($pid, SIGTERM)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php).  You'll need to find the process ID of the session first, though.  (You could probably grep the output of [`ps`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29) for it.  Or just use [`killall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) if you're not worried about collateral damage.)